# How to horizontal center grid element

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have 12 column grid. it written for generic purpose. In this i have only one element as child which occupies 6 columns. i can able to vertical align. but not center aligned. how to do that?

without modifying the grid system is there any way? please help me.

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
  justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-column: span 6;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
      <div>
        <span>1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

grid area is a combination of `row-start / column-start / row-end / column-end` and you can use it like this:

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
  justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-area:1 / 4 / 1 / 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div>
        <span>1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

more explanation for [grid-area](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-area.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Add the rules `grid-column-start` and `grid-column-end`, and remove `grid-column: span 6` from `.container div`. In your case, it should look like this:

```
.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  /*grid-column: span 6;*/
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 10;
}
```

```css
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
  justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  /*grid-column: span 6;*/
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div>
        <span>1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I totally agree with you. some time i have 3 elements some times 2. is there any generic approach other than manual calculation. since the style sheet shared with number of peoples..

Answer (score -3):

You could add text-align: center in the following class.

```
.container div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  grid-column: span 6;
  text-align: center;
}
```